# Generate configuration meta-data for SpringBoot tooling

Tags: spring-cloud

It would be nice if configuration meta-data would be generated for SpringCloud artifacts just like what is done for SpringBoot (i.e. the META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json files).

Is it foreseen?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but it seems that version 1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT already includes the requested feature...

Comment: you are correct, `spring-configuration-metadata.json` is in `1.0.1.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/286 for a request to generate a list of properties to be included for documentation.